# I found an electrical outlet hidden behind wood paneling. Do I need to cut the paneling and remove the outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I was hoping to quickly flip out a few electrical receptacles in my basement; however, I found that one of the outlets was connected to a outlet floating behind the wood paneling.

Is this okay given that that the receptacle is boxed in, or do I need to cut out the wood paneling on this corner to address and resolve somehow?

Hidden Box
[image]

Edit: I cut the paneling to expose the issue. It looks like it is pretty damaged and corroded. So, now should I be okay to just rewire the outlet as it was only with a new box and receptacle as long as I make the outlet accessible, correct? I wouldn’t mind having a couple of more outlets. It sounds like I should secure the wire and add clamps to the other already exposed outlet as well. Thanks all.

Exposed
[image]

Wear
[image]

Comment: So this outlet is inaccessible? But still live? Can you just remove the feed at the other end?

Comment: Do you have enough slack in the two main wires to eliminate the junction box and jumper wire? That would leave you with just the single box with outlet that can be cut in and mounted solving the problem.

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely a code violation, boxes have to be accessible without cutting the wall finish - paneling in this case.

The main problem with a buried junction box is that there's no way to know that there's a splice there when troubleshooting and there's no way to inspect the work inside.  Splices are common failure points and if the splice goes bad, it's a real pain to find and fix.  And a bad splice can definitely heat up, so it's a fire hazard.

Think about this:  even if inaccessible junction boxes were code compliant, would you trust those boxes in your wall?  I personally wouldn't trust either, not the one that's dangling nor the one that's attached to the stud.  None of the cables are strapped down, and I don't see any clamps where the cables enter the boxes.  Who knows what kind of dumpster fire might be inside those boxes.

So I'd say just bite the bullet and fix it.  If I am following the photos, you have three choices:

- Eliminate the dangling box - replace the cable that feeds these with one long enough to land right in the bottom receptacle box.  (This could be a lot of work.)
- Use a NM splice repair kit.  These do appear code compliant, they have a listing for repairs and don't have to be accessible.  Unfortunately they are junky and make an insulation displacement splice and I just don't trust them.
- Redo that dangling box so it's accessible.

So I'd probably be going with that last option, it is not much work.  You'd just remove that dangling box, set a box on the stud, and staple down the cable coming down into it.

It looks like there's enough cable to reach a box set at switch height.  Even though it will just wind up with a blank cover, it will look better at switch height than at some random height.  Add a short cable from that box to the receptacle below, also secured properly, splice, button everything up, and hang a picture over the blank cover.

Answer (score 3):

No, a "buried" box whether it has an outlet in it or not is unacceptable.

This box either needs to be exposed through the paneling with an outlet or just a cover or this run needs to be replaced with one without a box.

Answer (score 3):

If you can be 100% certain that you can disconnect *all* wiring going to and leading from this box (i.e. leave it totally disconnected from *all* possible sources of power), you should be fine in leaving it buried behind the paneling.

When disconnecting the cables at the other ends (be sure to get *both* ends), you'd not only want to cap off wiring, but I'd *strongly* suggest labeling the cabling that you're disconnecting to indicate that it goes to a buried box and *MUST NOT* be reconnected.

I'd use a Sharpie™ (or similar permanent pen) to write directly on the cable housing if at all possible. Adhesive labels can fall off over time, but an attached label (maybe card-stock and a zip tie) *and* direct marking would be a good "belt-and-braces" solution.

Comment: Note- "belt-and-braces" is, according to TIOT, an idiom from the UK that means something akin to "safe" or "reliable"; e.g. using both a belt *and* suspenders (braces) to hold up ones trousers is a good safe way to make sure they don't fall down.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, simplicity itself.  Put the wood panel back with a square hole just big enough for the receptacle box (not including its tabs). Diagonal it through the square hole, then settle it back into the hole so the tabs are flush with the wood (tabs on your side of the wood).  Fasten down with some short 1/2" wood screws (pre-drill to avoid splitting so near the edge).

Now the box is mounted flush to the wood (well very slightly proud by the thickness of the tabs).

Now, pull the old recep out, unhook all the wires, clean the rusty gook off of them with a cloth, use a Scotchbrite pad on the bared copper parts.  Clean up the box to the extent that is easy, but especially clean up the flats where the receptacle yoke will land so they are paint-free and rust-free.

Attach the safety grounds to the metal box.  Attach hot+neutral to a new receptacle. Remove the little "keeper squares" from the recep mounting screws, so the yoke will have hard flush metal-metal contact with the box.  That takes care of safety ground.

Fit a cover plate and you're done.

You can replace the metal box in-kind *if you really want to*, but I don't mind old rust if it's not continuing to get wet.

Answer (score 0):

The box must be uncovered and attached to something. The cable is Romex so I would change the box to one that has ears that would swing out when you turn the screws at the top and bottom of the box. These are usually plastic boxes. The Romex should be stapled within 8 inches of the box, but I do not think this is possible in your case. It looks like the switch box feeds a 4 in square box that is also berried. This box must have access and this needs to be corrected. You may have enough slack to feed the 4 in box directly but you still have to mount the 4 in box so you can access it

Comment: The box you are describing is called an “old work box”, and should have clips for the cable entry points so that stapling is not necessary to secure the cable

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. The box the previous person used is a standard gem box. Goto the hardware store and get yourself a pair of Madison hangers to secure the box once you replace paneling.
Replace paneling with a new piece that does not have the existing outlet hole.
Remove Romex from box.
Put paneling up and finish it if you need to paint or whatever.
Then use the gem to trace out a new rectangle hole to cut.
I suggest moving the new hole to the right a few inches.
Pull the existing Romex through the new rectangular hole. Slide cable into box holes with clamps.
Insert box and secure with Madison hangers.
Please ensure the bare copper wire is splice and attached to outlet.
Trim hot and neutral wires.
Done.

Comment: While this does provide the _how_, it doesn't answer the question asked which was "do I need to expose the box?". If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that we expect answers to, well, _answer_ the question asked. Nothing wrong with providing _additional_ info, tips, how-tos, etc, but please at least answer the question asked. Feel free to [edit] your post to first answer, then your how-to (with a bit of formatting) will be most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the wires. Put this in its place.  Reinstall paneling.
Tyco Electronics    Romex Splice Kit 2 Wire, 1/Clam
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-A22899-000/202204326

Unless you want the outlet, then just cut the paneling

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. While this accurately addresses one solution to the "how do I fix" question, that is _not_ the question that was asked. Please feel free to [edit] your post to answer the "do I need to fix" question, as asked.